# How to stream .ts file unchanged via udp

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, vlc, mpeg, transport-stream

I have a .ts file in my computer that I want to send via UDP as is, the standard 7 188 bytes mpeg packets in each udp message.  VLC and ffmpeg can send via UDP a mpeg that they create, but I don't want the file remuxed or transcoded in any way.  tsreader can do this in the most expensive version.  Is there any windows tool that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that both vlc and ffmpeg have options for copying the input codec parameters (ffmpeg for example -codec copy should not remux)

but still if you want something more straight-forward, go for tstools: http://tstools.berlios.de/
("tsplay:   Play (and possibly loop) a PS/TS file over UDP (using timing info) or TC")

good luck.